# How to sequentially create charts with Google Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have been trying a LOT of stuff to do this without success.

I have a JavaScript array (actually, a JSON array parsed in JavaScript) which has elements (the type of elements in the array is not important).
I want to loop though the array and sequentially create a chart corresponding to each of the elements in the array. All the charts are added to a div container.

So basically, I want to loop through the array, creating a chart for each element and appending the chart (whicH obviously have its own associated div) to a div container.

So for example, if I have 3 elements, create sequentially 3 charts and display them in the container div.

I tried something like this:

```
//Loop through the nodes on this Bayesian Network
for(var k = 0; k < current_bn.nodes.length; k++)
{
//Set the global variable current_graph_node's value to this node.
current_graph_node = current_bn.nodes[k]; //current_bn.nodes[k];

var chart_id = current_graph_node.node_id+"_div";
var graph_div = document.createElement("div");
graph_div.setAttribute("id", chart_id);
graph_div.setAttribute("class", "chart_div");

//Call the function to draw the map.
google.load('visualization', '1', {'callback':'drawChart', 'packages':['corechart']});
document.getElementById("twins_div").appendChild(graph_div);
alert("YES BACK");

}//END looping each node
```

And then I have defined the function drawChart as:

```
function drawChart() 
{
//Get the chart type required to represent this node.
var node_name = current_graph_node.node_name;
var node_id = current_graph_node.node_id;
var node_desc = current_graph_node.node_desc;
var node_type = current_graph_node.node_type;
var node_chart_type = current_graph_node.node_chart_type;
//var chart_title = current_graph_node.node_chart_title;

//create a DataTable for this
var data_table = new google.visualization.DataTable();

//TODO Should redefine these! It should not be static!
data_table.addColumn('string', node_name);
data_table.addColumn('number', 'Probability');

//Loop through the marginals of this node.
for(var i=0; i < current_graph_node.marginals.length; i++)
{

    //Get this marginal details
    var marg = current_graph_node.marginals[i];
    var label = marg.label;
    var value = marg.value;
    data_table.addRow([label, value]);

}//END appending marginals.

//Set the display options for this chart
var options = 
{
    //TODO This should not be static. perhaps have in JSON config filee
            node_chart_title
    title: node_name+' (Absolute 0 - 100% Scale)'+'\n'+node_desc,
    legend: { position: "none" }
    //hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
};

var id = node_id+"_div";
var chart=null;

if(node_type === "LabelledEN" || node_type === "BooleanEN"
    || node_type === "RankedEN" || node_type === "DiscreteRealEN" )
    chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById(id));
else
    chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(id));

//Now draw the chart
chart.draw(data_table, options);


//document.getElementById("twins_div").draw(data, options));

}//END method drawchart
```

But it is not working. What it does is it loops through the whole array, then draws the chart for only the last element.

The alert("YES BACK"), instead of being called for each of them AFTER going in drawChart, it calls alert("YES BACK") for each element in the array, then when exiting the loop, draws the chart for the last element (which I came to realise since the value of "current_graph_node" is overwritten each time around the loop.

For those who are interested, I am using AgenaRisk's API to read Bayesian networks and display charts for nodes that I am interred in to represent their probability distribution.
The array is a JSON array.

Comment: Just try to fiddle the basics in jsfiddle.net providing partial of JSON data.

Comment: Thanks but I actually have no problem with the JSON bit of the code. Everything works fine with it. It's just **sequentially drawing charts using google charts** that does not work.  The JSON bit (each of the node elements) just contain information about the data to be used on the chart. I know how to retrieve that. The only problem I have is the sequentially drawing charts part.

Comment: @enapupe Thanks very much for that website. I actually did not know about it.

Comment: The JSON part is to help people running your code in jsfiddle.net, it makes debugging a lot easier.

Comment: Also, I don't think google.load('visualization' is going to run more than once, since this is the call for the library, which triggers a callback just once.. The for loop should be inside the callback.

Comment: @enapupe is correct.  The google loader should only be called once for loading the Visualization API, and the loop should be inside the callback from the loader.

Comment: @enapupe thank you very much to you both for letting me know about that. Now I understand better how that function, which was very mysterious to me before works.  but even though I have tried what you suggested, it still doesn't display the charts. It's weird. Apparently, there is an error when it reaches line:            `chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById(id));`        That's where the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @enapupe's comment above, this is roughly the structure you want for your code:

```
function init () {
    for(var k = 0; k < current_bn.nodes.length; k++) {
        //Set the global variable current_graph_node's value to this node.
        current_graph_node = current_bn.nodes[k]; //current_bn.nodes[k];

        var chart_id = current_graph_node.node_id+"_div";
        var graph_div = document.createElement("div");
        graph_div.setAttribute("id", chart_id);
        graph_div.setAttribute("class", "chart_div");

        //Call the function to draw the map.
        drawChart();
        document.getElementById("twins_div").appendChild(graph_div);
        alert("YES BACK");
    }//END looping each node
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {'callback': init, 'packages':['corechart']});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Sorry to respond so late. been very busy lately. I have just tried what you ve suggested and it still does not work for me :(       Every time, I have realised, it stops when it reaches line:            `chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById(id));`        That's where the error(unknown to me) occurs.

Comment: fiddle the code in jsfiddle.net so we may help you.

Comment: You can also open the page in Chrome or Firefox and open the developer's console to see if there are any error messages (and there should be at least one).  Those error messages will help diagnose the problem.